# Gluster - split-brain monitoring

Tags: replication, monitoring

I know that the best things how to deal with split-brains is to avoid them. I have a traditional 1 x 3 replication set up. I am looking for an indicator (except of gluster logs) that tells that a split brain or any other type of error occurred. This then could trigger some other actions from my side, nevertheless, I can't sit and look into logs all day long waiting for an error there. Is there anything in gluster that would tell me that "something wrong has happened, take a look into logs" or "take some action" ?

Thanks for any hints in advance,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

For determining split-brains there is a command "gluster volume heal  info split-brain". This will list all the files which are in split-brain state. With this there is no need of monitoring split-brains in log messages.

Or You can use syslog/rsyslog to receive mails in case of split-brain event . Refer to : http://www.techrepublic.com/article/configure-it-quick-log-linux-system-events-with-syslog/ or https://www.dalemacartney.com/2012/08/19/configuring-syslog-in-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [gluster plugin for Nagios](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/System-Metrics/File-System/GlusterFS-checks/details).

It will tell you about the healing status. Split-brain is a particular case of file that is not getting healed properly.

Answer (score 0):

This link explains how to configure the glusterfs plugin using nagios :

http://gopukrish.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/monitor-glusterfs-using-nagios-plugin/